# How to check the unit test with powermockito?

Tags: android, testing, powermockito

Android how to check the unit test with powermockito

```
public void updateProfile(final UserLogin updateUser) {
    profileModelImple.updateUser(updateUser)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted () {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError (Throwable e) {
                    Timber.e("authenticationModel -> login " + e);
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(null);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext (Object user) {
                }
            });
}
```